# How to use vlookup when the data is not a perfect match?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have the following data in a worksheet

[image]

In another worksheet i have just the name of the fruits like

```
Apple
Apple (IV )
Apple(POS)
Grape (IV)
```

I am trying to find the correspondiong values from column M. Now `Vlookup` would work if the reference is perfect match and by using the formula `Vlookup("*"&Refence Cell&"*",Look-up range, Col#,FALSE)` i can get the data in some cases.

But in this case, vlookup doesnt seem to be working for Apple (IV ) since there is a blank space after IV and the ")" (2nd case) `OR` there is no space between apple and (POS) in the 3rd case `OR` the last case where there is no bags in the reference cell but in the input range there is a Grapes( IV Bags).

Is there a work around this?

Comment: Either you need to fix all the errors in the data or look into Fuzzy Lookups.  There are many addons that will help.

Comment: looks like you are in need of a variant of lookup function that can take a regex as one of its parameter